# How to query against fields of array of objects in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

I have a mongo collection which has the following document:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5c7ba3c0e30e6132f8b0c4ef"),
    replies: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId("5c7ba3c0e30e6132f8b0c4ef"),
            status: 'rejected'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all replies with status approved so I make the following query:

```
Collection.find({'replies.status': 'approved'})
```

and yet the document above appears in the results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of the query process.  I suspect one of your docs looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
  "replies" : [
  { "_id" : "R0", status: "rejected"}
  ,{ "_id" : "R1", status: "approved"}
  ]
}
```

The issue is that doing a `find` on an array will match any doc where AT LEAST one of the array entries matches; it does NOT filter the result to JUST those entries.   Here are two approaches.  Given this data setup:

```
var r =
[
{
    "_id" : 0,
  "replies" : [
  { "_id" : "R0", status: "rejected"}
  ,{ "_id" : "R1", status: "approved"}
  ]
}
,{
    "_id" : 1,
  "replies" : [
  { "_id" : "R2", status: "rejected"}
  ,{ "_id" : "R3", status: "rejected"}
  ]
}
,{
    "_id" : 2,
  "replies" : [
  { "_id" : "R4", status: "rejected"}
  ,{ "_id" : "R5", status: "approved"}
  ]
}
 ];
```

Approach 1:  Simple and the embedded array is small (dozens not 100s or 1000s of entries.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
// This will find all docs where ANY of the replies array has AT LEAST ONE      
// entry "approved."   It will NOT filter just those.                           
{$match: {"replies.status": "approved"}}

// Now that we have them, unwind and "refilter"                                 
,{$unwind: "$replies"}

,{$match: {"replies.status": "approved"}}
   ]);

{ "_id" : 0, "replies" : { "_id" : "R1", "status" : "approved" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "replies" : { "_id" : "R5", "status" : "approved" } }
```

Approach 2:  Use `$filter` if array is very large and using `$unwind` creates 1000s of docs.  This approach also is useful in preserving the structure of the original doc:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
// This will find all docs where ANY of the replies array has AT LEAST ONE      
// entry "approved."   It will NOT filter just those.                           
{$match: {"replies.status": "approved"}}

// To avoid $unwind, directly filter just "approved" and reset the replies      
// field back into the parent doc:                                              
,{$addFields: {replies: {$filter: {
                input: "$replies",
                as: "zz",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$zz.status", "approved" ] }
            }}
    }}

   ]);

/*                                                                              
{                                                                               
    "_id" : 0,                                                                  
        "replies" : [                                                           
                     {                                                          
                         "_id" : "R1",                                          
                             "status" : "approved"                              
                             }                                                  
                     ]                                                          
        }                                                                       
{                                                                               
    "_id" : 2,                                                                  
        "replies" : [                                                           
                     {                                                          
                         "_id" : "R5",                                          
                             "status" : "approved"                              
                             }                                                  
                     ]                                                          
        }                                                                       
}
```