# MongoTemplate search by a field in a nested list

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have a `list` of `MainItem` objects like below

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5ee40defc4b47b54a223120f",
      "name":"Item 1",
      "subItems":[
         {
            "_id":"111",
            "name":"cat One name",
            "description":"cat item description"
         },
         {
            "_id":"222",
            "name":"cat Two name",
            "description":"cat item description"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"5ee40defc4b47b54a223120f",
      "name":"Item 1",
      "subItems":[
         {
            "_id":"333",
            "name":"cat Three name",
            "description":"cat item description"
         },
         {
            "_id":"222",
            "name":"cat Two name",
            "description":"cat item description"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"5ee40defc4b47b54a223120f",
      "name":"Item 1",
      "subItems":[
         {
            "_id":"333",
            "name":"cat Three name",
            "description":"cat item description"
         },
         {
            "_id":"111",
            "name":"cat One name",
            "description":"cat item description"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is a search by `subItem` name. So if search like "cat Th" my result should be like below (should return list of `SubItem` list that matches name),

```
[
    {
        "_id":"333",
        "name":"cat Three name",
        "description":"cat item description"
    }
]
```

I need to do this by using mongoTemplate and this is the one I'm using to get the result,

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(MainItem.class)).distinct("subItems", new BasicDBObject("subItems.name", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "^cat Th")), BasicBSONObject.class).into(new ArrayList<>())
```

Instead of getting the matching SubItem in list, I get all distinct SubItems, What am I doing wrong here?

(Same SubItem can be in different MainItem lists, in those scenarios distinct SubItems matching name should be there)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to query against fields of array of objects in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581154/how-to-query-against-fields-of-array-of-objects-in-mongodb)

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I'm not familiar with aggregate. Can we achieve something similar to this using mongotemplate as well?

Comment: Also according to that example, I want to get the list of reply objects, not the parent objects with the list. And also in my case. The same SubItem can be there in two different MainItem. So in scenarios like that only distinct SubItems should be there in the list

Comment: You can get the desired results using the `MongoTemplate#aggregate` method. The aggregation will have `$project` to filter (`$filter` aggregation array operator) the `subItems` array, and `$group` stage to get the distinct values. This is a link to documentation for [Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation Framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation).

Comment: @prasad_  If that's a decent answer, copy and paste into the answer section below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research in aggregation framework and using aggregate method in MongoTemplate, I came up with this solution to fix my issue.

```
final UnwindOperation unwind = unwind("subItems");
final GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("subItems");
final ReplaceRootOperation replaceRoot = replaceRoot("_id");
final MatchOperation matchName = match(Criteria.where("name").regex("^" + name, "i"));
final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(unwind, group, replaceRoot, matchName);

mongoTemplate
  .aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(MenuItem.class), SubItem.class)
  .getMappedResults();
```